# How to use Selenium and Scrapy to get the comments pagenation links from this page?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I tried to extract comments and comments page numbers from [this page](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTY5NDg2MzY5Ng==.html), but I couldn't. That part of the page doesn't seem to be loaded into Selenium.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from scrapy import Spider



class Test94Spider(Spider):
    name = “t94”
    allowed_domains = ["youku.com"]
    start_urls = (
                'http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTcxMzQzMzk5Mg==.html?beta&spm=0.0.0.0.vm99s6&from=y1.12-97'
    )

    def __init__(self):
        display = Display(visible=0, size=(1280, 800))
        display.start()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()


    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "qPager_1"))
                    )
            self.logger.info(element)
        except Exception:
            self.logger.info('Nothing found')

        nxt = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='qPager_1']/ul/li[@class='current']")
        title = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class='title']/span[2]").text

        print(‘Title:’, nxt)
        print(‘Next:’, title)
```

In the above code I only get the `title`, but I can't get `nxt` link, I get this error instead:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
```

Any idea how to get elements in the comment part of the page?

Comment: What do you mean by _"doesn't seem loaded"_? What error do you get? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The page comes up with a 404 error. How about adding some code to your question also.

Comment: @JRodDynamite I get `no such element` error. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Grasshopper I've updated the link and added the code.

Comment: @XO39 Getting an internal server error...

Comment: @Grasshopper I'm not getting that error! *-*